# Windows command-line program to change the volume of an mp3 file

Tags: windows, command-line, audio, mp3

I can use audacity to increase the volume of an MP3 file.  However, if I want to use this on a regular basis it's a hassle, since I have to fire up audacity, load the file, increase the volume and finally export it back to MP3.

Is there any command-line program I can use that will increase the volume?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`mp3gain` can do this.  It is open source and is available here:

https://mp3gain.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Yep, using mp3gain too. Has both command line and GUI interfaces.

Comment: its good tool for sure

Answer (score 1):

mp3gain is outdated now.

I use ffmpeg for this.

https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/AudioVolume

Comment: Why do you say it's outdated? Last update was 2018 but if it does what it does well and it still runs on Windows 10/11 systems what's the problem?