# Any good mp3 volume normalizer?

Tags: mp3, ipod

I tried to use [MP3Gain](https://superuser.com/questions/14635/windows-command-line-program-to-change-the-volume-of-an-mp3-file) to keep mp3 files with the same volume.

The problem is: when I re synchronize all files into my IPod, some musics get too loud.

So, it seems MP3Gain is not fixing volume at all or there is a problem with synchronization software.

Perhaps I should "re add" files into ITunes 10.1 library again.

Meanwhile, is there a another good mp3 volume normalizer for testing playback in IPod?

Answer (score 4):

To clarify this (I hope), there are a couple of items at play:
1) The volume level of your MP3s
2) The soundcheck values associated with your MP3s
3) Whether soundcheck is enabled for playback within iTunes and/or playback on the device

If your tracks are in iTunes, and Soundcheck values have been calculated, then, when you play those files in iTunes or on your iPod, they'll play at a steady volume (assuming Soundcheck has been enabled on iTunes and on your iPod).

If you MP3Gain the files (i.e. change their volumes to a steady level), and then resynced them to your device, it's possible that Soundcheck values aren't immediately recalculated, and the old Soundcheck values will cause the device to play the tracks at unlevel volumes!

All that to say: unless you're playing those MP3 files on a device that doesn't support Soundcheck/Replay Gain, there's no reason for you to use MP3 Gain on them, since iTunes/iPod's Soundcheck does the job just as well (a second reason not to use MP3 gain is that it may cause you to lose Album Gain (the relative gain/loss in volume from one track to another on a single album) information.

Incidentally: [MediaMonkey](http://www.mediamonkey.com) supports MP3 Gain / Replay Gain (Track Gain & Album Gain) / Soundcheck (for iPod sync), so you can use it if you wish to play around with this.

Disclosure: I work on MediaMonkey

Answer (score 1):

How about the ["Sound Check"](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2425?viewlocale=en_US) feature in iTunes?

[image: Sound Check]

---

If you already have Sound Check on, there's a possibility that your iPod is applying old (pre-MP3gain) information to the already-normalized songs.

Comment: Yes sound check here is checked. I think there is something to do with IPod. No matter I try to fix my mp3 files with MP3Gain, when I resynch all files, the louder ones keep on louder. The firmware is update so I don't know what to do. Only 2 albums keep louder than it should be. Playing in IPod is annoying because of volume differences, but when playing in PC you see no difference between volumes.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I have done

1. Select items with CTRL and right click on any music item in list,
   choose *Get Info*
2. Now go to *Options* tab
3. You should see the *Volume slider*
   adjusted near 100%, just slide it to
   *None*

   [image]
4. Uncheck your files and Synch
5. Check your files and Synch again

Comment: Well I run MP3Gain again setting all files to 90db.
Forced some louder files to sound below 90db. But since I found a way in ITunes to "unset" music volume, everything seems to be working now.